# switch out variable name using function argument in r

Tags: r

I want to build a function that takes a variable name as an argument so if I have some code like:

```
function(df, variable = NULL) {
  df <- df %>% filter(variable > 10)
  test <- c()
  for (i in c(1:10)) {
    test2 <- df$variable[i] - df$othervariable[i]
    test <- c(test, test2)
  }
  return(test)
}
```

Then I can swap out the variable simply by plugging in the name through the argument. I've thought about doing it like `df['variable']` instead. But this does not solve the problem in the dplyr filter function and also it returns a dataframe rather than `df$variable` which is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

`df$variable` is the same as `df[,'variable']` (the `,` is important) which is also the same as `df[['variable']]`

Comment: What you mean is if `variable="foo"` then `df[[variable]]` is the same as `df$foo`. Use `$` if you can write the name in your code, or use `[[]]` if you want the value of an expression. A different approach is needed for `dplyr` because it uses non-standard evaluation. Rewrite the `filter` using base R functions instead.

Comment: There's no way to specify an argument as an object rather than a character? So I can just write, `df$variable` where `variable = foo` (not a character), and therefore `df$foo`. Or in dplyr: `df %>% filter(variable > 10)` where `variable = foo` and therefore `df %>% filter(foo > 10)`

Comment: @Spacedman yes I solved problem by just making my dplyr calls into base package equivalents, but I'm surprised there's no way to call a variable name as an argument. Luckily I only had a few lines to change, but it could be much worse.

Comment: If you do `df[[variablename]]` it evaluates `variablename` and becomes the equivalent of `df$whateverthevalueofvariablenameis`. In dplyr you need to look into "non standard evaluation" and the use of quosures.

Comment: @Spacedman that's what I'm looking for. Nice find. quosures - never heard of it